# C# FluentValidation reading pattern from constant not working

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I'm having a problem reading a static string from a class, that holds my pattern for validation.
When I debug, I see that the curly braces are getting cast into square brackets.
This is my class:

```
public static class ArticleConstant
{
    public const int LengthOfArticleNumber = 9;
    public static readonly string PatternArticleNumber = "^[A-Z0-9]{9}$";
}
```

I also tried

```
public static readonly string PatternArticleNumber = "^[A-Z0-9]\{9\}$";
public static readonly string PatternArticleNumber = "^[A-Z0-9]{{9}}$";
public static readonly string PatternArticleNumber = @"^[A-Z0-9]{9}$";
public static readonly string PatternArticleNumber = $"^[A-Z0-9]{9}$";
```

But none of it worked.
This is my actual Validation rule:

```
this.RuleFor(article => article.Number)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithLocalizedMessage(() => ValidationErrorMessages.IsRequired)
            .Length(ArticleConstant.LengthOfArticleNumber)
            .WithLocalizedMessage(() => ValidationErrorMessages.DefinedSized)
            .Matches(ArticleConstant.PatternArticleNumber)
            .WithLocalizedMessage(() => ValidationErrorMessages.MustNotContainAnySpecialCharacter);
```

When I enter the pattern directly into the Matches function everything works like expected.

Could someone please explain to me what's happening here?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Have you tried `/^[A-Z0-9]{9}$/`

Comment: Tried it. The curly braces are getting parsed correctly but validation still fails. Even with a very easy pattern like

`public static readonly string PatternArticleNumber = "^[A-Z0-9]*"`

the validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now by using

```
public const string PatternArticleNumber = "^[A-Z0-9]{9}$";
```

seems like `static readonly` was doing something, so that the validation failed.